# MYSQL - Understanding this SELECT and UNION ALL query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union, alias

I have this code, courtesy from [Tom Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/966491/tom-mac) but I would like to make some changes but I cannot understand how it works.

I'm trying to add two Date columns along side by adding `UNION ALL SELECT date1, date2 FROM person` and also trying to insert it in between existing select functions.

How would I go about adding those two columns from the same table onto my result?

Here is the provided code that I am trying to adjust:

```
select person as Names,
sum(splitScore) as Split_Count,
sum(activeScore) as Active_Count
from
(
select Name1 as person, 
case when Name2 is null then 1 else 0.5 end as splitScore,
case when Active='True' and Name2 is null then 1 when Active='True' and Name2 is not null then 0.5 else 0 end as activeScore 
from person where Name1 is not null
union all
select Name2 as person, 
case when Name1 is null then 1 else 0.5 end as splitScore,
case when Active='True' and Name1 is null then 1 when Active='True' and Name1 is not null then 0.5 else 0 end as activeScore 
from person where Name2 is not null
) t inner join roster s on s.name = t.log
group by person
;
```

Comment: The two 'selects' in the union must have matching columns. So, add those fields to both, and to the outer select. Also, add them to the group by

Comment: when you want to try doing something like this on your own... just take apart the query.  work with the most nested parts first and add the info you need.  try to understand the joins and aggregation, make sure you're getting the correct results each time you add a part back in or together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two queries that are being joined must contain the same fields in the same order.  So, see your example below with additional fields:

```
select person as Names,
sum(splitScore) as Split_Count,
sum(activeScore) as Active_Count,
newfield1, newfield2
from
(
select Name1 as person, 
case when Name2 is null then 1 else 0.5 end as splitScore,
case when Active='True' and Name2 is null then 1 when Active='True' and Name2 is not  null then 0.5 else 0 end as activeScore, 
newfield1, newfield2 
from person where Name1 is not null
union all
select Name2 as person, 
case when Name1 is null then 1 else 0.5 end as splitScore,
case when Active='True' and Name1 is null then 1 when Active='True' and Name1 is not null then 0.5 else 0 end as activeScore, 
newfield1, newfield2 
from person where Name2 is not null
) t inner join roster s on s.name = t.log
group by person
;
```

A standard UNION can look like:

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1
UNION
SELECT field1, field2 from table2
```

Your query obviously has additional complexity